# Finding multiple unique matches from List<object> where two criteria have to be different

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, linq

I am having trouble selecting the first item in a list that is unique based on two fields, JOB_ID and EMPLOYEE_ID.

Each job should only be assigned to one employee (the one with the lowest OVERALL_SCORE), then move on and assign the next employee.

The List Objects are as follows:

**JobMatch.cs**

```
public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
public int JOB_MATCHES_COUNT { get; set; }
```

**EmployeeMatch.cs**

```
public int EMPLOYEE_ID { get; set; }
public int EMPLOYEE_MATCHES_COUNT { get; set; }
```

**Rankings.cs**

```
public int JOB_ID { get; set; }
public int EMPLOYEE_ID { get; set; }
public int TRAVEL_TIME_MINUTES { get; set; }
public int PRIORITY { get; set; }
public int OVERALL_SCORE { get; set; }
```

> Rankings.cs gets an overall score based on the travel time field and
>   number of matches an Employee/Job has.

**EmployeeMatch.cs**

```
+-------------+-------------------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | EMP_MATCHES_COUNT |
+-------------+-------------------+
|           3 |                 1 |
|           4 |                 1 |
|           2 |                 3 |
|           1 |                 4 |
+-------------+-------------------+
```

**JobMatch.cs**

```
+--------+-------------------+
| JOB_ID | JOB_MATCHES_COUNT |
+--------+-------------------+
|      1 |                 1 |
|      2 |                 2 |
|      3 |                 2 |
|      4 |                 4 |
+--------+-------------------+
```

**Ranking.cs** (shortened as to not fill the screen)

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| JOB_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | OVERALL_SCORE |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
|      4 |           3 |           800 |
|      4 |           4 |           800 |
|      3 |           1 |           800 |
|      3 |           2 |          1200 |
|      2 |           1 |          1600 |
|      2 |           2 |          1800 |
|      4 |           1 |          2000 |
|      4 |           2 |          2100 |
|      1 |           1 |          6400 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

Basically, the idea is to select the first unique Employee and Job in this list and then the best matches will be put into a separate list, something like the following for the above scenario:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| JOB_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | OVERALL_SCORE |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
|      4 |           3 |           800 |
|      3 |           1 |           800 |
|      2 |           2 |          1800 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

I tried the following but it didn't work as intended:

```
var FirstOrder = (rankings.GroupBy(u => u.JOB_ID)
.Select(g => g.First())).ToList();

var SecondOrder = (FirstOrder.GroupBy(u => u.EMPLOYEE_ID)
.Select(g => g.First())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is choosing first element and then removing corresponding elements from list to make sure next choice is unique, as below:

```
var rankings = new List<Rankings> {
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 4,EMPLOYEE_ID= 3, OVERALL_SCORE=  800 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 4,EMPLOYEE_ID= 4, OVERALL_SCORE=  800 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 3,EMPLOYEE_ID= 1, OVERALL_SCORE=  800 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 3,EMPLOYEE_ID= 2, OVERALL_SCORE= 1200 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 2,EMPLOYEE_ID= 1, OVERALL_SCORE= 1600 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 2,EMPLOYEE_ID= 2, OVERALL_SCORE= 1800 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 4,EMPLOYEE_ID= 1, OVERALL_SCORE= 2000 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 4,EMPLOYEE_ID= 2, OVERALL_SCORE= 2100 },
    new Rankings{  JOB_ID= 1,EMPLOYEE_ID= 1, OVERALL_SCORE= 6400 },
};
var cpy = new List<Rankings>(rankings);
var result = new List<Rankings>();
while (cpy.Count() > 0)
{
    var first = cpy.First();
    result.Add(first);
    cpy.RemoveAll(r => r.EMPLOYEE_ID == first.EMPLOYEE_ID || r.JOB_ID == first.JOB_ID);
}
```

result:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| JOB_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | OVERALL_SCORE | 
+--------+-------------+---------------+
|      4 |           3 |           800 |
|      3 |           1 |           800 |   
|      2 |           2 |          1800 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: i see. it's because i assigned JOB_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID in wrong order for list initiation, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Really, if you're trying to get the best score for the job, you don't need to select by unique `JOB_ID/EMPLOYEE_ID`, you need to sort by `JOB_ID/OVERALL_SCORE`, and pick out the first matching employee per `JOB_ID` (that's not already in the "assigned list").

You could get the items in order using LINQ:

```
var sorted = new List<Ranking>
( 
  rankings
    .OrderBy( r => r.JOB_ID )
    .ThenBy( r => r.OVERALL_SCORE ) 
);
```

...and then peel off the employees you want...

```
  var best = new List<Ranking>( );
  sorted.ForEach( r1 => 
  {
    if ( !best.Any
    ( 
      r2 => 
        r1.JOB_ID == r2.JOB_ID 
        || 
        r1.EMPLOYEE_ID == r2.EMPLOYEE_ID
    ) )
    {
      best.Add( r1 );
    }
  } );
```

*Instead of using Linq* to produce a sorted list, you could implement `IComparable<Ranking>` on `Ranking` and then just sort your rankings:

```
public class Ranking : IComparable<Ranking>
{
  int IComparable<Ranking>.CompareTo( Ranking other )
  {
    var jobFirst = this.JOB_ID.CompareTo( other.JOB_ID );
    return
      jobFirst == 0?
        this.OVERALL_SCORE.CompareTo( other.OVERALL_SCORE ):
        jobFirst;
  } 

  //--> other stuff...

}
```

Then, when you Sort() the Rankings, they'll be in JOB_ID/OVERALL_SCORE order. Implementing `IComparable<Ranking>` is probably faster and uses less memory.

Note that you have issues...maybe an unstated objective. Is it more important to fill the most jobs...or is more important to find work for the most employees? The route I took does what you suggest, and just take the best employee for the job as you go...but, maybe, the *only* employee for job 2 may be the same as the best employee for job 1...and if you put him/her on job 1, you might not have anybody left for job 2. It could get complicated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use `System.Linq.Distinct` method reinforced with the custom equality comparer `IEqualityComparer<Ranking>`. The `System.Linq` provide this method out of the box.

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Ranking>
{
    public bool Equals(Ranking l, Ranking r)
    {
        return l.JOB_ID == r.JOB_ID || l.EMPLOYEE_ID == r.EMPLOYEE_ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Ranking obj)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The trick here is with the `GetHashCode` method, and then as simple as this

```
rankings.Distinct(new Comparer())
```